# ios6 "translate" method interference?

Tags: javascript, ios6

How come the following does not work on ios6, but replacing "translate" with "something_else" makes it work just fine?

```
<style>
    .body{position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;z-index:2;}
</style>
<div class="body"></div>
<script language="javascript">
    var add_output = function(html,parent){
        parent.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',html)
        return parent.childNodes[0];
    }
    var new_output = add_output('<div style="position:absolute;top:10px;left:10px;z-            index:1;" class="new_output">0</div>',document.body);
    new_output.translate = function(d){
        this.innerHTML = d;
    }
    document.querySelector('.body').addEventListener('touchmove',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        new_output.translate(e.touches[0].pageX);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a new [`translate`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/global-attributes.html#the-translate-attribute) attribute added in HTML5. You are merely setting it to `true`, since [by definition](http://es5.github.com/#x9.2) all objects evaluates to `true`.